# is there a way to prevent data in a flash drive from being copied

Tags: usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, privacy-protection, copy-protection

I want to give a USB flash drive to a friend but I don't want him to copy the data in USB or add anything to it
is it possible so he could only read the files without the ability to do anything else?

Comment: If you can read a file, you can copy it.

Comment: so there is no way?

Comment: Short of you looking over his shoulder and holding a bat to his head while he reads the files, I don't so how this could be accomplished.

Comment: I don't have a bat, can I use knife or something else?

Comment: Encrypt the files on the drive you do not what anyone to have access to, they can copy them but cannot decrypt the files.

Comment: Better duplicate of this question....http://superuser.com/questions/484142/how-to-protect-copying-files-out-of-flash-memory

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the answer is no. If it can be read, it can be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to "Prevent data on Flash drive to be copied"

***One way is to use third party software likes***

http://www.nexcopy.com/usb-copy-protection/

http://www.kakasoft.com/

Now the above will require you purchasing those software. so not sure about budget or how critical the data is

If you goal is simply secure these file

***Alternative***

one alternative zip these files and password protect them, Again this is not what you asked.

i use 7zip and then just password protect my files

Comment: these programs dont work

Comment: 3rd party Software recommendations are not considered answers here on SU.

Comment: Why isn't the question deleted then or migrated to the correct forum? I mean i get it people are flagging it down