# How to protect file on USB from being copied?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

How can I prevent file on USB flash drive to being copy and paste either via right click or drag and drop copy to other device that is hookup to it like a PC ? The file will be PDF, document file, JPG or some other image file, and some movie file etc?

The scenario is the file will be needed to be just viewable to show people but they cannot copy any part of it out from it other than admin level that create/authorize full control of it.
Example is like a person on a field trip is bring some presentation stored on USB flash drive and show it on field premise to showcase company stuff like brochure, powerpoint, concept drawing, sales figure etc but we do not allowed them to have those file on the USB drive to being able to copied off to client's PC or even their own home without authorization. Not even a phrase or JPG image from a particular document etc. Pretty much just view only mode.

i found in the Amazon, it indeed has such product FYEO copy protection USB flash drive. the link is 
[http://www.amazon.com/FYEO-Partition-Protection-Encryption-Waterproof/dp/B01C5ZIL6C?ie=UTF8&m=A1BZ6154GHMVA5&qid=1462416629&ref_=sr_1_26&s=merchant-items&sr=1-26](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C5ZIL6C)

[http://www.amazon.com/FYEO-Professional-Collection-Anti-Virus-Protection/dp/B01C3P40P0?ie=UTF8&m=A1BZ6154GHMVA5&qid=1462416629&ref_=sr_1_48&s=merchant-items&sr=1-48](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C3P40P0)

Comment: If it can be read, it can be copied.... otherwise just encrypt the drive, which is essentially what those drives are doing you linked.

Comment: @acejavelin, if it is encrypt the drive, that means nobody can view it unless he/she has the password. but copy protection usb flash drive  has big difference with encrypted flash drive. FYEO copy protection USB flash drive can view the content in the USB, but the other also can't copy the content off the USB. it can prevent your important information spreading with limits range.

Comment: if you can open a document or file, you can copy it... Simple as that, the drive has no possible way of knowing if a file is being opened or copied, it looks exactly the same from the drives perspective, a simple read operation. Read the description of the FYEO drive, it is simply a 2 partition drive, one public and private/encrypted partition, no magic other than by the marketing department

Comment: Impossible. If I open the jpg and can't copy, what is to stop me taking a screen shot

Comment: @KevinWang Upload it online somewhere, make it accessible post authentication of some sort and done. Don't make your rep. carry a flash drive to presentation, at places they won't even let you carry those into their office.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way to prevent data in a flash drive from being copied](http://superuser.com/questions/1041135/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-data-in-a-flash-drive-from-being-copied)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect copying files out of flash memory?](http://superuser.com/questions/484142/how-to-protect-copying-files-out-of-flash-memory)

Comment: @Dave try to imagine, if the photo stored in the USB are high resolution image, if you take screen shot, the picture will become unclear, how can you sell or show your customer this is your idea.

Comment: @acejavelin without use it, how can you confirm that if the file can open, then sure it can copy. we design to two partition because one partition is used for sharing with other, the copy protection partition is used for the content you don't wish other people can view it.

Comment: @KevinWang No offense, but if I can open or read a file, for example, a text document, why could I just not save it to another location. If I can read any file with a tool like `dd`, I can make a perfect copy of the file in another location. I do like the idea of a two partition flash drive for this purpose, but I don't think it is the solution for the OP.

Answer (score 6):

In the end, but reading *is* copying. To "read" a file practically means to "copy into RAM", otherwise programs couldn't work with it. And once that's done, you can't possibly stop every single program from having a "Save As..." or "Copy to..." option.

The same applies even to humans. If someone reads a phrase, they will remember it and can write it down by hand. (Although more likely they'll just take photos of the whole presentation.)

Maybe it would be enough to put watermarks on everything?

Comment: we use layered FSD Technology, that means there is no Cache in the computer. we can stop the people who have good memory can remember all thing and write it down. if you take photo, you will spend lots of time to do it again.

Comment: How it does answers the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's not practically possible because if someone can read it, he/she can also copy it. Even if you control the machine/computer, they can still capture the photos of the screen. Secudrive offers secured USB drives: http://www.secudrives.com/products/USB-security that is something similar to Amazon copy-protection drive you've mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -2):

The one asking this question is I think not worried with the print screen option for doing it needs more time. There are actually flash drives now available for this. The only problem is the price. But it you want to do it with your own it cal still be done. The best method is to convert some of your files into .exe files. But the chance is that those files can be mistaken as viruses so that when you open your flash drive but you forgot to off your antivirus, the files will be damaged or maybe automatically being deleted. Just leave a reply if you are still interested on it.

Comment: _"The best method is to convert some of your files into .exe files."_ No, if want to hide files, you should encrypt the drive.