# Remove a file after being opened in my USB flash drive

Tags: usb, video

I want to have a specific video file to be removed after being played only once...

assuming I have a video file in my flash drive called **My_Video.mp4**, whenever I play and finish this video I want it to be deleted from the drive. Also I want to protect this video to not be copied or moved...

Thanks

Comment: Likely not feasible.

Comment: For the device you need, got to 1:45 at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4y9NtHlJvbY

Comment: In theory a custom firmware that deletes the file after serving it exactly once could work. But [you](https://superuser.com/a/1073300/432690) [cannot](https://superuser.com/a/484145/432690) suppress copying.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect file on USB from being copied?](https://superuser.com/questions/1073275/how-to-protect-file-on-usb-from-being-copied)